# Checking if an object is array-like

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to check if an object is "array-like", like for these types of objects:

- Arrays (duh)
- Typed Arrays (Uint8Array, etc), these will return false when `Array.isArray` is used
- arguments object
- NodeLists*
- There are a few other ones that I can't think of off-hand

I suppose you could check for the presence of a `.length` property, but non-array-like objects can contain the `.length` property. I guess the thing these all share in common is the array accessor.

Comment: check for the existence of `[0]`?  but that'll fail for empty array-likes.

Comment: Considered that, but my function could be passed an empty array.

Comment: Strings can also use the square-brackets, you're just referring to a character in that string. Not sure if you'd consider Strings to be array-like or not (I do)

Comment: I'd consider .pop to be a good one to check - basically everything array-ish should have that; check for NodeLists separately and || together

Comment: DOM elements are not array-like, but NodeLists are.

Comment: @RalphWiggum Are DOM elements array-like? I don't see how a `div` can be an array. Though you might be thinking of jQuery which returns an array of elements.

Comment: maybe just insist that your function is always passed something array-like, and hope for the best  :)

Comment: Also for performance reasons, these days you're better off requiring strict parameter types. So you should avoid pandering to misuse of your API!

Comment: if([].slice.call(theArrayish).push(-1)){}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As best I've found in my research on this topic, you have only a couple choices:

1. You can look only at the `.length` property and accept any object that seems to have an appropriate `.length` property that isn't any other things you know you should eliminate (like a function).
2. You can check for specific array-like objects (`HTMLCollection`, `nodeList`) and bias in favor of them.

Here are two options for the first method - one that doesn't accept a zero length and one that does (these incorporate suggestions by gilly3 and things we see in jQuery's similar function):

```
// see if it looks and smells like an iterable object, but don't accept length === 0
function isArrayLike(item) {
    return (
        Array.isArray(item) || 
        (!!item &&
          typeof item === "object" &&
          item.hasOwnProperty("length") && 
          typeof item.length === "number" && 
          item.length > 0 && 
          (item.length - 1) in item
        )
    );
}
```

This, of course, reports `false` for items with `.length === 0`, If you want to allow `.length === 0`, then the logic can be made to include that case too.

```
// see if it looks and smells like an iterable object, and do accept length === 0
function isArrayLike(item) {
    return (
        Array.isArray(item) || 
        (!!item &&
          typeof item === "object" &&
          typeof (item.length) === "number" && 
          (item.length === 0 ||
             (item.length > 0 && 
             (item.length - 1) in item)
          )
        )
    );
}
```

Some test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3brjc/

2)  After checking to see that it's not an actual array, you can code to check for specific kinds of array-like objects (e.g. `nodeList`, `HTMLCollection`).

For example, here's a method I use when I want to make sure I include nodeList and HTMLCollection array-like objects:

```
// assumes Array.isArray or a polyfill is available
function canAccessAsArray(item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // modern browser such as IE9 / firefox / chrome etc.
    var result = Object.prototype.toString.call(item);
    if (result === "[object HTMLCollection]" || result === "[object NodeList]") {
        return true;
    }
    //ie 6/7/8
    if (typeof item !== "object" || !item.hasOwnProperty("length") || item.length < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // a false positive on an empty pseudo-array is OK because there won't be anything
    // to iterate so we allow anything with .length === 0 to pass the test
    if (item.length === 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (item[0] && item[0].nodeType) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;        
}
```

Comment: I store objects with integer ids in an array, with the id as the array index.  Since these come from a database that starts numbering records at 1, there is no element at index 0, even though the length is greater than 0.  I use an array rather than an object because sometimes I like to use array methods like `.filter()`.  My array would fail your check.  Seems like the first line of your function should contain a check for `item instanceof Array`.

Comment: It would be safer to check `item[item.length - 1]` instead of `item[0]`.  You would yield fewer false negatives.

Comment: @gilly3 - It has `Array.isArray()` as the first line now.  What I first copied in here was from another project was a method that assumed the caller had already checked to see if it was an actual array.  I edited that code to be more specific to this question.  Also, `instanceof Array` has issues if you're ever using data from other windows/frames.  That's why I generally avoid it.  If you're guessing whether it's an array, you will have to decide what guesses you want to use.  No guesses are perfect.  For your specific case, you may as well just check for `.length` and go from there.

Comment: @gilly3 - it's your specific case that thinks that `[length - 1] is safer than `[0]`.  I can think of many cases where the opposite is true.  If you want to include items in your check that have undefined elements, then you pretty much have to eliminate checking any specific element and just check for the existence of `.length`.  We're talking about guessing strategies here and when you try to get more specific than that, which guessing strategy works better depends entirely upon the type of data you're testing against and whether you'd rather bias toward a false positive or false negative.

Comment: Good point about accessing from other windows.  That's an easy one to forget about.

Comment: How about `((item.length - 1) in item)`?  Even if the last element in an array is `undefined`, you can still check for the existence of the element using `in`.

Comment: @gilly3 - that seems like a possibility.  Have to first make sure `.length > 0`.

Comment: @gilly3 - I incorporated your suggestions into a function for the first option in my answer.

Comment: I think you should accept array-like objects of `length == 0` as well. It might not make a difference if the only purpose is to iterate the thing, but it does when non-array-like things are handled specially (e.g., enumerated with `for in` instead). Failing to recognice them might cause greate issues.

Comment: This method looks a lot like [jQuery's `isArrayLike`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ca0086b55a158d8a4347f94254878d6dc5dd90ed/src/core.js#L481) :-)

Comment: @Bergi - As I say in the answer, I think the user of this needs to decide on that.  I don't think there's an absolute right/wrong.  I'll that as another choice.

Comment: I see, but I tend to "it's an issue for a generic function" instead of "*is generally not an issue*"

Comment: @Bergi - I hadn't seen the jQuery version, but I did incorporate something from it because a function always has `.length` so that would be good to avoid.  I added a version that allows `.length === 0`.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the object is *iterable* :

```
function isIterable(o){
 return (o!=null && typeof(o[Symbol.iterator])==='function');
}
```

Careful though, ***returns true for strings***. If that's a problem, exclude them :

```
function isIterable(o){
 return (o!=null && typeof(o[Symbol.iterator])==='function' && typeof(o)!=='string');
}
```

Then either access the elements using the iterator or if you want to use the regular *array[0]* way, just add a check for length property.

---

**Complete isArrayLike function :**

```
function isArrayLike(a){
 return (
  a!=null &&
  typeof(a[Symbol.iterator])==='function' &&
  typeof(a.length)==='number' &&
  typeof(a)!=='string'
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to find out if an object is one of a list of known array-like types you could do this:

```
if (/( Arguments|NodeList|Collection|Array)\b/.test({}.toString.call(obj))) {
    //obj is array-like
}
```

But for a more comprehensive solution keep reading:

From MDN:

> The term [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#array-like_objects) refers to any object that doesn't throw during the length conversion process described [below]. In practice, such object is expected to actually have a length property and to have indexed elements in the range 0 to length - 1. (If it doesn't have all indices, it will be functionally equivalent to a sparse array.)
>
> [Normalization of the length property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#normalization_of_the_length_property)
>
> The length property is converted to an integer and then clamped to the range between 0 and 2^53 - 1. NaN becomes 0, so even when length is not present or is undefined, it behaves as if it has value 0.

So there are two different definitions for array-like object. The first one is any object which doesn't throw during the normalization of the length property. We can test for that with try/catch:

```
function isArrayLike(o) {
    try {
        0 in o;// throws if o is a primitive such as a string
        +o.length;// throws if length property cannot be converted to a number
        return true;
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

The second definition is any object that satisfies the above and also has a length property and indexed elements in the range of 0 to length - 1:

```
function isArrayLike(o) {
    try{
        var length = o.length,            // Throws if o is null or undefined
            isArrayLike = Array.isArray(o)// o is an array. No further checks needed.
            || length===+length           // Checks if length property contains a Number. Throws if length can't be converted to a Number
            && (length-1 in o && length>0?// Throws if o is not an object.
                length%1? 0: length<Math.pow(2,53):// length-1 key exists and length>0 so require safe integer
                !length                   // else require length===0
            );
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
    return !!isArrayLike
}
```

Notice that unlike the accepted answer, my answer doesn't distinguish between functions and other objects. That's because functions are objects and can be array-like too! In fact old versions of Safari are known for this.

Another difference from the accepted answer is that my function returns false with fraction and non-safe-integer lengths such as 1.1 and Infinity.

My function is also designed to be minified so that it takes the least amount of space possible! Just run it through a JavaScript minifier such as jscompress.com.

All rights reserved!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends what you mean by array-like. Probably something you could iterate with a for loop like this:

```
for (var i=0, l=obj.length; i<l; ++i) {
  var item = obj[i];
}
```

So then the test is simple:

```
function isArrayLike(obj) {
  if (!obj) return false;
  var l = obj.length;
  if (typeof l != 'number' || l < 0) return false;
  if (Math.floor(l) != l) return false;
  // fast check
  if (l>0 && !((l-1) in obj)) return false;
  // more complete check (optional)
  for (var i=0; i<l; ++i) {
    if (!(i in obj)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Of course, this won't catch arrays which are sparsely populated, but then again, are they really being used as arrays? NodeLists and the like won't be sparsely populated.

**Enjoy!**

Answer (score 0):

An Array is a value that has following properties:

1. Its of type object
2. It has *length* property which is equal or greater than 0.
3. All the value based keys are numeric and is greater than or equal to 0.

- Exceptions:
- length
- Value is a function.

```js
function isArrayLike(value) {
  if (typeof value === "object" && !!value) {
    const isArray = Array.isArray(value);
    const allNumericKeys = Object.keys(value).every((k) =>
      (!isNaN(k) && +k >= 0) ||
      k === "length" ||
      typeof value[k] === "function"
    )
    const hasLength = value.length > 0
    return isArray || (allNumericKeys && hasLength)
  }
  return false
}

console.log('Array: ', isArrayLike([]))
console.log('Array Like: ', isArrayLike({1: 'a', 2: 'b', length: 3}))
console.log('Array Like with function: ', isArrayLike({1: 'a', 2: 'b', length: 3, foo: () => {} }))
console.log('Array Like with negative keys: ', isArrayLike({ "-1": 'a', "-2": 'b', length: 1}))
console.log('Array Like without length:', isArrayLike({1: 'a', 2: 'b' }))
console.log('Node List: ', isArrayLike(document.querySelectorAll('p')))
console.log('null: ', isArrayLike(null))
console.log('String: ', isArrayLike('Test'))
console.log('Number: ', isArrayLike(123))
```

```html
<div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems like the XY problem to me.

## “Can it be an array?”

…is what really matters. Just check if it’s *iterable* by iterating it.

```
function if_iterable(value/*: any */) {
    try {
        [...value];
    } catch(error) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
} // -> boolean
```

Or by checking if it supports *the iterable protocol*.

```
function if_iterable(value/*: any */) {
    return !!(value?.[Symbol.iterator]);
} // -> boolean
```

Exclude `Map`s, strings, and `String`s, if you’d like to. They’re iterable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for **either array or array-like**:

```js
function isArrayLike(item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item) || (
        typeof item[Symbol.iterator] === 'function' &&
        Number.isInteger(item.length))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

const map = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]);
const set = new Set(["a", "b", "c"]);
const obj = new Object({ type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white" });
const array = new Array(["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]);

function args_of_func(a, b, c) {
    return isArrayLike(arguments);
}

console.log("For Object");
console.log(isArrayLike(obj));
console.log("For Array");
console.log(isArrayLike(array));
console.log("For Array-like");
console.log(args_of_func(1, 2, 3));
console.log("For Map");
console.log(isArrayLike(map));
console.log("For Set");
console.log(isArrayLike(set));
```

If you are looking for **array-like but not array** then:

```js
function isArrayLike(item) {
    if (!Array.isArray(item) &&
        typeof item[Symbol.iterator] === 'function' &&
        Number.isInteger(item.length)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

const map = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]);
const set = new Set(["a", "b", "c"]);
const obj = new Object({ type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white" });
const array = new Array(["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]);

function args_of_func(a, b, c) {
    return isArrayLike(arguments);
}

console.log("For Object");
console.log(isArrayLike(obj));
console.log("For Array");
console.log(isArrayLike(array));
console.log("For Array-like");
console.log(args_of_func(1, 2, 3));
console.log("For Map");
console.log(isArrayLike(map));
console.log("For Set");
console.log(isArrayLike(set));
```

Just copy the `isArrayLike` function. The rest of it is just for testing.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to check if an object is array-like or not, even if there are no elements in it, using this function here:

```
isArrayLike = function (_) {

    _[0] = 0; return [].slice.call(_).length >= Object.values(_).length;
}
```

This uses a little hack I accidentally discovered that allows you to determine if an object is (1) an array, (2) array-like, or (3) object / object-like.

The only downside is that it does not work correctly for array-likes that have object-like properties added, such as `arguments`

Answer (score -1):

***Technically***, (pretty much) every object is "array-like"  (because of type coercion of `undefined`) according to the standard ([ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification §7.3.17, `CreateListFromArrayLike (obj [, elementTypes] )`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createlistfromarraylike)):

> ## 7.3.17 CreateListFromArrayLike (obj [, elementTypes] )
>
> The abstract operation CreateListFromArrayLike is used to create a List value whose elements are provided by the indexed properties of an array-like object, *obj*. The optional argument *elementTypes* is a [List](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type) containing the names of ECMAScript Language Types that are allowed for element values of the [List](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type) that is created. This abstract operation performs the following steps:
>
> 1. [ReturnIfAbrupt](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-returnifabrupt)(*obj*).
> 2. If *elementTypes* was not passed, let *elementTypes* be (Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, Symbol, Number, Object).
> 3. If [Type](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*obj*)
>      is not Object, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 4. Let *len* be [ToLength](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tolength)([Get](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-get-o-p)(*obj*, `"length"`)).
> 5. [ReturnIfAbrupt](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-returnifabrupt)(*len*).
> 6. Let *list* be an empty [List](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type).
> 7. Let *index* be 0.
> 8. Repeat while *index* < *len*
>
>    1. Let *indexName* be [ToString](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring)(*index*).
>    2. Let *next* be [Get](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-get-o-p)(*obj*, *indexName*).
>    3. [ReturnIfAbrupt](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-returnifabrupt)(*next*).
>    4. If [Type](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*next*)
>         is not an element of *elementTypes*, throw a **TypeError** exception.
>    5. Append *next* as the last element of *list*.
>    6. Set *index* to *index* + 1.
> 9. Return *list*.

<sup>Generated via https://www.browserling.com/tools/html-to-markdown</sup>

Answer (score -3):

I say nothing beats the simplicity and expressiveness of extending native objects:

```
Object.prototype.isArrayLike         = function(){ return false; };
Array.prototype.isArrayLike          = function(){ return true; };
NodeList.prototype.isArrayLike       = function(){ return true; };
HTMLCollection.prototype.isArrayLike = function(){ return true; };
```

This approach could cause conflicts between frameworks, however, I recommend keeping your distance from a framework whose `isArrayLike` function does not what the name suggests.

Comment: It would be better to use an instanceof check instead of prototype pollution in this case.

Comment: Just for excercise - in what situation could this conflict with another framework or script? Especially if you use some very obscure property name like `__ěščřžýáíéů` and an alias `isAL` for that stored hidden inside your scope for your convenience - and use it like `if(obj[isAL])`? I really think anything akin to `_ř_` should be enough and doesn't even need an alias by the way.

Comment: @ElDoRado1239 I've been scarcely using this approach for years without any effort of obscuring the names, and never ran into a single conflict.