# How to check if an object is array-like but not array

Tags: javascript

We can check whether a variable is array-like or array by [Checking if an object is array-like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24048547/1772898).

How to check if a variable is [array-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#working_with_array-like_objects) but not an array?

**Update 1:**

What I have tried so far is:

```
const car = { type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white" };
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

function sum(a, b, c) {
    console.log(Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(arguments));
    return a + b + c;
}

console.log(Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(car));
console.log(Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(cars));
result = sum(1, 2, 3)
```

I have use `function sum` because the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) says:

> arguments is an array-like object

So far it yields correct result. Please let me know whether I am on the right track.

Comment: Add `&& !Array.isArray(variable)`

Comment: ...or `!(variable instanceof Array)`.

Comment: I am assuming it has `Array.prototype.forEach` method then it is array-like.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail If an object supports `.forEach()` it doesn't mean it's array-like.

Comment: Updated the question with details.

Comment: @Barmar yes I have checked. `Array.isArray(variable)` and `Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(variable)`, both works.

Comment: Why are you assuming that? You linked to another question that has answers showing better ways to do it.

Comment: @Barmar no. That question if for "array or array-like". This question is about "array-like but not an array".

Comment: I know. But then you add the `!Array.isArray` condition to it.

Answer (score 0):

OP Here, The short answer is:

```
const car = { type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white" };
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

function args_of_func(a, b, c) {
    return isArrayLike(arguments);
}


function isArrayLike(item) {
    if (!Array.isArray(item) &&
        typeof item[Symbol.iterator] === 'function' &&
        Number.isInteger(item.length)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log("For Object");
console.log(isArrayLike(car));
console.log("For Array");
console.log(isArrayLike(cars));
console.log("For Array-like");
console.log(args_of_func(1, 2, 3));
```

`isArrayLike` will return `true` for only array-like objects, and `false` for arrays or other type of objects.

The following solution is for education purpose only. Here, I am doing the same tests multiple way (for my future reference). This is derived from the referred question.

```
function isArrayLike(item) {
    if (!Array.isArray(item) &&
        !(item instanceof Array) &&
        !Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(item) &&
        Object.prototype.toString.call(item) !== '[object Array]' &&
        typeof item[Symbol.iterator] === 'function' &&
        Number.isInteger(item.length) &&
        item.hasOwnProperty("length") &&
        Array.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item, "length")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `!Array.isArray(item)` implies `!Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(item)` (more commonly written `!(item instanceof Array)`). You don’t have to check both. Also better to use `Object.hasOwn` (or its more broadly compatible equivalent `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call`) than `.hasOwnProperty` as a method of an object, since some array-like collections could also be dually name-keyed collections that could plausibly contain something named `hasOwnProperty`, maliciously or not.

Answer (score 0):

arguments in a function is an object with keys and values you do not need to check if it is array like.

```js
function sum(a,b,c){
  console.log(typeof arguments, arguments);

}

const car = { type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white" };
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

sum(1,2,3)
sum(car);
sum(cars);
sum(...cars);
```

If you want to sum every value passed to function sum just loop throuht arguments using for..in loop

```js
function sum(){
  let total = 0;
  for(const key in arguments){
    total += arguments[key];
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(sum(1,2,3));

// strings as arguments
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
console.log(...cars);
```

Make sure every arguments[key] is a number which can be summed otherwise strings will be concatenated

Comment: I know i do not "check if it is array like". I used the argument just to have an array-like object. The question is not about how to use the `arguments` variable.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail In this case maybe this article can help [link](https://daily.dev/blog/why-do-you-need-to-know-about-array-like-objects)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going through it right now.